# Matlabcontrol and Java Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, tomcat, servlets

I have successfully used the matlabcontrol jar to run Matlab remotely from Java on my local machine.

However, when I put my code onto a Java 7 servlet hosted on a Tomcat 8.0 server on Eclipse EE Luna and ran the same code, Matlab started up just fine, but then gave me this error:

matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException: Support code location could not be determined. Could not get path from URI location.

**Note: This was running matlabcontrol-4.1.0**

I tried downgrading to matlabcontrol-3.0.1 using the RemoteMatlabProxy class.  It executed Matlab remotely just fine, but then gave me an error:

Undefined variable "matlabcontrol" or class "matlabcontrol.MatlabConnector.connectFromMatlab".

Immediately I thought of compatibility issues, but I was able to run Matlab just fine in Eclipse SE **with both matlabcontrol versions**.  That suggests that the problem is actually with EE.  Does anyone know of any additional procedures I have to follow in order to get this running on a servlet?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer:  It's not really possible.

Tomcat does not play nice with the Matlab 3rd party libraries, so what I did instead was use my tomcat server to broadcast down to a Java client that could then use matlab control.

Javascript/HTML -> Java/Tomcat -> Java/Matlab

I did this using Web sockets (ws:// instead of http://), and it works very well!